# ${param_name} вместо значения параметра в JSP

Tags: java-ee, java

Народ, что я делаю не так? Изучаю SpringMVC по примерам разным ([вот](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) один из них).

Вот код контроллера:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "JCG Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

Вот тело странички:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Spring 4.0.2 MVC web service</h1>
<h3>Name : ${name}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

А на странице только:
**Spring 4.0.2 MVC web service

Name : ${name}**

Почему?

**UPD**

вот мой web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>configContextLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Вот бин:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

А вот и сам [проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlkhyp5fq62b7vr/SpringMVCExample.rar?dl=0) на IDEA. Помогите товарищи!!!

Comment: Страничка jsp? ViewResolver настроен?

Comment: @a_gura, все настроено.

Answer (score 1):

Товарищи, все заработало, когда я убрал следующее, сгенерированное IDEA-ей из web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

Вот только я не понимаю, почему не работало из-за этого...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у тебя ошибки в `web.xml` или `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` (наверное, косяк тут). Проверь, чтобы их содержимое совпадало с тем, что в примере. И полный код проекта выложи, а то так нельзя точно сказать.

Comment: я сделал уже три примера! все проверено перепроверено!